# How to set individual site under MultiSite WordPress installation to use different language?

Tags: wordpress

How to set individual site under MultiSite WordPress installation to use different language?

I have a WP installation with MultSite setting.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language

says

```
Multi-Site Installations

If you have a site network (WordPress multisite), the language is set on a per-blog basis through the "Site language" option in the Settings->General subpanel.

You can set the default language for the entire network under the Network Admin->Settings panel ("Default Language").
```

But in my Setting -> General subpanel, I can't see a "Site language" option.

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a plugin called qTranslate. It allows you to setup any number of languages for each site in a network. It is very good. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/

Answer (score 0):

You should add language files:

1. On your site server, create a new folder in your */wp-content* OR */wp-includes* directory called */languages*.
2. Upload the *.mo* file to the *languages* folder.